# Как загрузить файл в зависимости от названия страницы в ReactJS + React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Интересует вопрос подгрузки JSON (и не только) в зависимости от `pathname` страницы. Да, легче всего будет использовать один файл, но если у меня их несколько и я не могу ничего с этим поделать...

Вот код `<Router>` в `App.js`:

```js
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact>
        <Main/>
      </Route>

      <Route exact path="/news/:category" render = {props => <Category {...props} /> }/>
      </Switch>
```

Вот код примерный код, который я хочу реализовать:
(Код не рабочий. Это "набросок")

```
class Category extends Component{

    loadJSON(filename){
        return require("./" + filename + ".json");
    }


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.loadJSON(this.props.match.params.category);
    }
```